# VSCodeが黒い画面から進まず起動しない。

Tags: macos, vscode

VSCodeをインストールしましたが、起動せず [黒い画面](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASzkX.png) で止まったままです。
メニューをクリックしてもメニューなど表示されず、何もできません。
正常にインストールする方法はないでしょうか。

### 環境

- mac OS Catalina 10.15.6
- VScodeは最新のものをダウンロード

### 試したこと

1. 再インストール
2. PATHを通した後、ターミナルで `code --disable-gpu` を実行したが、変わらず黒い画面で止まってしまう。
3. その後、ターミナルで `sudo code` と実行したところ正常に起動しましたが、閉じるとまた黒い画面で止まってしまいます。

`sudo code` で生成されたユーザーのパーミッションを変えると引き続き使用出来るようですが、
正規のインストール方法とは思えないので、その他手立てはないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

### 試したこと7/25追加分

管理者権限を持ったユーザを作成（ユーザ（フルネーム）とアカウント名（ホームディレクトリ名）を統一）
そのアカウントでVSCodeをインスール　問題なくインストールできました。
管理者権限を持ったユーザを作成（ユーザ（フルネーム）とアカウント名（ホームディレクトリ名）を違うものに）
そのアカウントでVSCodeをインスール　問題なくインストールできました。

### どんなインストールをしたか

1. 公式サイトよりダウンロード　（https://code.visualstudio.com/）
   ※chromeの翻訳機能を使って日本語にしてダウンロードしました。
2. ダウロードディレクトリにてZIPファイルをダブルクリックで解凍
   ※デフォルトのアーカイブユーティリティ.appを使用
3. そのままダウンロードディレクトリで「Visual Studio Code.app」をダブルクリック
   ※この時も黒い画面で止まって進みませんでした。
4. アプリケーションディレクトリに移動させていないことに気付き移動させる。
   ※移動後も起動しませんでした。
5. 再インストールなどを繰り返したが症状は変わらず
6. PATHを通して `code --disable-gpu` などを実行
   ※これでも改善されず
7. sudo codeにて立ち上がることを確認。
   ※sudo codeで生成されたディレクトリを通常通りインストール（１、２のインストールの仕方）したディレクトリに上書きなどしましたが、1度きり立ち上がってその後は、黒い画面から進みませんでした。
8. sudo codeで生成されたディレクトリや通常通りインストール（１、２のインストールの仕方）した.appやディレクトリを削除して再インストール。それでも改善されず。
9. sudo codeを実行して、生成されたディレクトリ（アカウント名）に権限を追加。立ち上がることを確認。
10. 試したこと7/25追加分を行った。
11. 新しく作ったアカウントでVSCodeを使用中。（問題なく使えてはいる）
    ※現状ここです。

### 影響がありそうなこと

- ユーザ（フルネーム）とアカウント名（ホームディレクトリ名）を統一していない
- MAMPをインストールしている
- ホームディレクトリが `sudo code` で生成れたディレクトリになってしまっている

### 8/1追加分

生成されたディレクトリ（アカウント名）
`●●●●●“?LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8?LOGNAME=“●●●●●”?OLDPWD?PWD=`
※●●●●●は普段使っているアカウント名
※アカウント名とは下記のページ内にある画像を参考に記述しています。

[macOS のユーザアカウントやホームフォルダの名前を変更する - Apple サポート](https://support.apple.com/ja-jp/HT201548)

### code --verbose --log によるエラーメッセージ

```
WARNING: IPC handle "/Users/●●●●●“
LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8
LOGNAME=“●●●●●”
OLDPWD
PWD=/Users/●●●●●”/Library/Application Support/Code/1.47.2-main.sock" is longer than 103 chars, try a shorter --user-data-dir
[main 2020-07-31T16:30:04.767Z] Could not delete obsolete instance handle Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, unlink '/Users/●●●●●“
LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8
LOGNAME=“●●●●●”
OLDPWD
PWD=/Users/●●●●●”/Library/Application Support/Code/1.47.2-main.sock'
    at Object.unlinkSync (original-fs.js:976:3)
    at Object.doStartup (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:624:856)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5) {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'unlink',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/Users/●●●●●“\n' +
    'LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8\n' +
    'LOGNAME=“●●●●●”\n' +
    'OLDPWD\n' +
    'PWD=/Users/●●●●●”/Library/Application Support/Code/1.47.2-main.sock'
}
[main 2020-07-31T16:30:04.770Z] Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, unlink '/Users/●●●●●“
LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8
LOGNAME=“●●●●●”
OLDPWD
PWD=/Users/●●●●●”/Library/Application Support/Code/1.47.2-main.sock'
    at Object.unlinkSync (original-fs.js:976:3)
    at Object.doStartup (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:624:856)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5)
[main 2020-07-31T16:30:04.770Z] Lifecycle#kill()
```

Comment: `sudo` は通常、管理者権限が必要な場面でのみ使うコマンドです。今回の場合であればインストール方法にもよりますが、VSCode を起動するだけなら (sudo は) 不要なはずです。

Comment: cubick様 コメントありがとうございます。どのようなインストールをしたか追記いたします。

Comment: 最近更新されたらしいこの記事を参考に再インストールしてみるとか。[MacOSでVisual Studio Codeをインストールする手順](https://qiita.com/watamura/items/51c70fbb848e5f956fd6)

Comment: kunif様 コメントありがとうございます。何度か再インストールもしておりましてその際に参考にさせていただいたサイトです。再度インストールの際にもう一度参考にしたいと思います。

Comment: dtraceでシステムコールをトレースを取れば、何かわかるかもしれません。こちらにはMacの環境がなく確かめていませんが、dtraceの使い方は https://qiita.com/hnw/items/269f8eb44614556bd6bf が参考になると思います。

Comment: akira ejiri様 コメントありがとうございます。dtraceについては、実行した経験がないため、上記サイトなどを参考にして検討してみます。

Comment: 影響がありそうなこととして、項目を追加しました。

Comment: 「アカウント名」とは何のアカウント名ですか？

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/80497 昨年の件ですが、この方はアンチウィルスソフトウェアの影響で起動できない事例に遭遇されたようです。なんらか起動を監視するようなソフトウェアをインストールされてていないでしょうか?

Comment: nekketsuuu様コメントありがとうざいます。
アカウント名はシステム環境設定のユーザとグループより確認できる
ホームディレクトリにも使われてるもののことです。
https://support.apple.com/ja-jp/HT201548
↑このページの画像にあるアカウント名です。
（ユーザ（フルネーム）と同じものにしていないです。）

Comment: Kouki.W 様 コメントありがとうございます。
以前は、ESET Smartをインストールしていましたが、
現状では、削除しています。

Comment: アカウントの問題かと思い本日、新しいユーザを作ってインストールしてみました。そのアカウントでは問題なくインストールできました。↑上記にも追記しております。

Comment: macOS においてフルネームとユーザーネームが違う状況というのはよくありそうなので、今インストールなさろうとしているユーザーにおける他の設定がこの状況を招いているのではないかと思っています（ふたつを揃えたユーザーにおいてインストールできたのは環境がフレッシュになったからでは、という仮説です）。`code --help` に書かれている `code --verbose --log trace` で何かしら関係しそうなログが出力されはしないでしょうか？

Comment: 別の管理者権限を持ったユーザであれば問題なくインストール＆使用可能とのことなので、現在のログインユーザがどういった権限になっているか念のため確認してみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: nekketsuuu様
返信遅くなりすみません。コメントありがとうございます。上記の件やってみます。
それと、生成されたユーザですが、下記のように長い名前となっており、
●の部分は元々使っているアカウント名（ホームディレクトリ）で
それに.bash_profileにある記述を足したようになっています。
●●●●●“?LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8?LOGNAME=“●●●●●”?OLDPWD?PWD=

Comment: Sugiyama Koichi様 コメントありがとうございます。ログインユーザの権限を確認しました。管理者権限になっているようで問題ないようでした。

Comment: code --verbose --log traceを実行したところ
やはり長いことがエラーとなっているようです。
以下に分けて貼っていきます。

Comment: ‘ls-la ~’で確認できる’.atom’ディレクトリの所有者はrootのなってませんか？

Comment: packet0 様 コメントありがとうございます。.atomディレクトリ確認しました。
所有者は、自分になってました。