# macでvscodeをインストールしても起動しない。

Tags: macos, vscode

使用しているMacには以前VSCODEをインストールしていましたが、クラッシュしてしまったためアンインストール行い、その後再インストールしたあと起動した際に「code が予期しない理由で終了しました。」というエラーメッセージが表示され、起動しません。
再度アンインストールを行い、インストールしても改善されない状況です。
どなたか解決のヒントをご存知でしたら教えてください。

Comment: この記事を参考に状況を追記してみてください。[VSCodeが黒い画面から進まず起動しない。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/68795/26370) 他にはこんなものが参考になるかも。[コマンドから VSCode を起動できない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/73886/26370), [VScodeを初期化するには](https://teratail.com/questions/319188), [macOSからVS Codeをアンインストール＆再インストールする](https://qiita.com/bolte/items/7ad3a835aafa91c860af), [MacOS - VSCodeをインストールしたが起動しない](https://teratail.com/questions/278006), [macOS で Visual Studio Code を使うためのアレコレ (2021/01/01)](https://qiita.com/satokaz/items/6a6a0d9b6489ec2d1803)

Comment: 環境の情報を [edit] して追記いただけますか。VS Code をどのようにインストールしたかや、Mac のバージョン情報などが欲しいです。